# do in background split not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask

please i want to know what is wrong with this code, if i try to split, it just crashes my app, but without the split line of code my app runs sucessfully and returns a response from my server with the delimeter "|" here is the code:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type= params[0];
    String login_url="somelink.com/somelink.php";
    if(type.equals("login")){
        try {
            String username= params[1];
            String password= params[2];
            URL url= new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String data=URLEncoder.encode("n", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
            data+="&" + URLEncoder.encode("p", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                result += line;
            }
            String[] words=result.split("\\|");
            StringBuilder ch=new StringBuilder();
            ch.append(words[0]);
            String check=ch.toString();
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return check;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you see in the log what exactly is happening? Say, what kind of exception is thrown?

Comment: that is the problem, am using my android device to test the app, since my avd doesn't work on my computer

Comment: You know you can easily log in to your device via `adb`. You can see logcat on the device.

Comment: please how can i do that?

Comment: OK, you'll have to look up details. (I haven't done Android programming for many years.) But, there are two ways. You can actually connect your device  to your computer via `adb` and open a shell in your device (Android is just a Linux computer). Go to your app directory and find the logcat. (2) If you use an IDE like Android Studio, if you run your app from the IDE, the logcat automatically shows up on your IDE log window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only obvious thing I can see is that you are probably accessing an element that does not exist. This line:

```
ch.append(words[0]);
```

It's possible that the length of the `words` array, in some cases, can be zero (e.g., because `line` is empty, etc.), and you are trying to access a non-existent element.

All you have to do is add `if` statement to check if you have a non-empty array before you do `words[0]`.